# [Apache Tapestry]: Page content as a stream/or string

Tags: java, tapestry

I would like to get the page content as a stream/or a string from a Page.class directly.

At the moment: I have to go through the route:

```
String uri = linkSource.createPageRenderLink(AnotherPage.class).toAbsoluteURI();
IOUtils.toString(uri, "UTF-8")
```

The problem with this approach is the call to `toAbsoluteURI()` makes the framework feel like the request is made from *an external source*; and it asks the user to login again; which should not be the case, as its one tapestry page accessing the other within the same application.

Note: I am not trying to "redirect" to `AnotherPage.class`. I would simply like to get another page's content as String without having to go via `toAbsoluteURI()` etc.

Alternatively, getting another page's content as Stream works too.

I am using `Apache Tapestry 5.4.1`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the tapestry-offline module. It lets you obtain the HTML from a Tapeatry-generated page quite easily.

https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-offline

Answer (score 0):

Have the method `onActivate` return an implementation of a `StreamResponse`, e.g.

```
public StreamResponse onActivate(Long productId) {
    return new TextStreamResponse("text/csv", convertProductToCsv(productId));
}
```

By default a page returns a template, but in this way you override that behaviour.

Check out this page: https://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToStreamAnExistingBinaryFile.